# Unity ResolutionFailedException for System.Web.Mvc Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

My WebApp is a combination of WebForms pages and MVC 4 pages.

Using Unity, I am getting the following exception.

**Exception Type**:

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException, Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.1.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

**Message**:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProvider", name = "(none)".  Exception occurred while: while resolving.  Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type ModelMetadataProvider does not have an accessible constructor.  At the time of the exception, the container was:
Resolving System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProvider,(none)
```

with an `Inner Exception` of:

**Message**:

```
The type ModelMetadataProvider does not have an accessible constructor.
```

**Stack Trace**:

```
at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForNullExistingObje ct(IBuilderContext context)  
at BuildUp_System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProvider(IBuilderContext )  
at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)  
at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)  
at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)  
at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
```

I consistently get the same resolution exception for the following types:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ITempDataProvide  
System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncActionInvoker  
System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker  
System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProvider  
System.Web.Mvc.IViewPageActivator
```

In Application_Start, I am setting up the IoC with:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfigurator.GetContainer()));
```

...where `GetContainer` returns all the registered types and `UnityDependencyResolver` is-a `IDependencyResolver`

Any ideas what is causing the issue?

Thanks,
--Ed

Comment: Do you have tour unity config? Have you set the dependency resolver for MVC?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how the container instance returned by `UnityConfigurator.GetContainer()` behaves exactly, but I assume it tries to resolve by itself alone the `ModelMetadataProvider` when needed. This `ModelMetadataProvider` has some dependencies that your container does not know that only the initial MVC resolver can resolve. By 'initial MVC resolver' I mean the result of `DependencyResolver.Current` before you call `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(...)`.
So, you need to implement a proxy over your own container and use as fallback the initial MVC resolver.

A quick example of how the proxy's implementation should look like:

```
public class MvcDependencyResolver:System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IDependencyResolver _resolver;

    private readonly System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver _fallbackResolver;

    public MvcDependencyResolver(IDependencyResolver resolver, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver fallbackResolver)
    {
        this._resolver = resolver;
        this._fallbackResolver = fallbackResolver;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if ((this._resolver.IsRegistered(serviceType)) || (serviceType.IsClass))
        {
            try
            {
                return this._resolver.GetService(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
            }
        }
        return this._fallbackResolver.GetService(serviceType);
    }
```

And then, in `Application_Start()` you overwrite the MVC resolver with a instance of this proxy, like this:

```
var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
var resolver = bootstrapper.Run();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MvcDependencyResolver(resolver, DependencyResolver.Current));
```